# correct placement of setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I can't seem to find the correct use of the setinterval() in my code.
It should refresh every second with 9 new random colors.

I already tried to place my code in an arrow function with a nested loop, hoping that this would initiate the interval for every loop it completes.

This however hasn't solved anything.
Reference the full code down below:

```js
let test = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    addRandomColorToSquare();
  }
}

setInterval(test, 1000);


let addSquareToDOM = function(color) {
  let square = document.createElement('div');
  square.className = 'square';
  square.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.body.appendChild(square);
}

let addRandomColorToSquare = function() {
  const randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  let rgbColor = `rgb(${randomRed}, ${randomGreen}, ${randomBlue})`;

  addSquareToDOM(rgbColor);
  test();
}
```

Comment: Why is `addRandomColorToSquare` calling back to your interval function `test();` again? The interval will trigger every second to add 9 elements. You will be nesting indefinitely with this code, hence the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when running the above.

Answer (score 5):

`setInterval` will generate the divs every second, but calling `test();` recursively will just run it infinitely and never let the DOM update. Then the callstack is exceeded and the script dies.

**Don't call `test()` recursively**. Call it **only** from `setInterval`.

Then you need to give the div elements some height so you can have some pixels to render the background colours on.

```js
let test = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    addRandomColorToSquare();
  }
}

setInterval(test, 1000);


let addSquareToDOM = function(color) {
  let square = document.createElement('div');
  square.className = 'square';
  square.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.body.appendChild(square);
}

let addRandomColorToSquare = function() {
  const randomRed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const randomGreen = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  const randomBlue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);

  let rgbColor = `rgb(${randomRed}, ${randomGreen}, ${randomBlue})`;

  addSquareToDOM(rgbColor);
}
```

```css
div { display: inline-block; height: 10px; width: 10px; }
```